# Thymeleaf action return object from list

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf as template engine. Now i want to return a single object from a list when submitting a form.

But i get this error message:

> Failed to instantiate [here.my.object]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException] with root cause

The object i want to return inherit from an abstract class, but it's already initialized, because it comes from the list. So why it doesn't work?

Here some code:

```
<div th:each="tool : ${toolList}">
        <form th:action="@{/execute}" method="POST" th:object="${tool}">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th th:text="${tool.name}"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Some output</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn">Execute</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And here the method from the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/execute")
public ModelAndView executeMethod(Tool tool) {

    tool.execute();

    return new ModelAndView("view/overview");
}
```

"Tool" is the abstract class.

Comment: Please show your bean configuration XML file.

Comment: I have no custom config file. Spring boot does it on its self.

Comment: Well... your issue is not even naive as it looks like. Problem is, that you are trying to bind a `Tool` object for a list of `Tool` objects. I see that you have an `each` expression which generates multiple forms. There's a tough obstacle.